# Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f11001b

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I have this error and I don't even know where to search for it.
I tried cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating cache etc. but nothing works.

This is how fragment and XML look like. I don't even have getText or getString methods in fragment, so it's not easy to find the error and debug it.
It's a multi-module application broken down by features. There is an app module and several features. The app contains actity and navigation.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f11001b
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:453)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:546)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:762)
    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:216)
    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206)
    at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2451)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2421)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7462)
```

```
class GeoWeatherFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentGeoWeatherBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel by viewModel<GeoWeatherVM>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentGeoWeatherBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val launcher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { map ->
                if (map.values.all { it }) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permissions granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    viewModel.handle(PermissionEvent.Granted)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Permissions are not granted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    viewModel.handle(PermissionEvent.Revoked)
                }
            }
        val permissions = Permissions(requireContext(), launcher, viewModel)

        val adapter by lazy {
            Adapter()
        }
        binding.recycler.adapter = adapter

        permissions.checkPermissions()

        viewModel.viewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
            when (state) {
                ViewState.RevokedPermissions -> {
                    binding.permissions.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                is ViewState.Success -> {
                    binding.permissions.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (state.location != null) {
                        val latitude = state.location.latitude.toString()
                        val longitude = state.location.longitude.toString()
                        viewModel.getWeather(latitude, longitude)
                        viewModel.getForeCast(latitude, longitude)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        viewModel.weather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it != null) {
                binding.city.text = it.location.name
                binding.country.text = it.location.country
                binding.temp.text = it.current.temp_c.toString()
                binding.feelsLike.text = it.current.feelslike_c.toString()//"Feels like ${it.current.feelslike_c.toString()}"
                binding.wind.text = it.current.wind_kph.toString() //"Wind ${it.current.wind_kph.toString()} km/h"
                binding.condition.text = it.current.condition.text
                val icon = it.current.condition.icon.replace("//", "https://")
                binding.image.load(icon)
            }
        }
        viewModel.foreCast.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.submitList(it?.forecast?.forecastday)
        }
        viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            when (it) {
                States.Loading -> binding.progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                States.Success -> binding.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                States.Error -> {
                    binding.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.permissions.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    //binding.permissions.text = "No Internet"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

And XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    tools:context=".ui.GeoWeatherFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/temp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/geo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/city" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feels_like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wind" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feels_like" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/condition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/condition"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_forecast" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupNav()

        enableEdgeToEdge()
    }

    private fun setupNav() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.navHost)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.weatherFragment -> hideBottomNav()
                else -> showBottomNav()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showBottomNav() {
        binding.navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun hideBottomNav() {
        binding.navView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**One of the below could be the root cause for this issue:**

1. In a class file you're setting test on a widget but not passing a string variable. E.g. `myTextView.setText(myInt)`

Solution is to convert int to a string using `String.valueOf()` and then pass it to `setText`.

2. You are passing an int in place of a String in a layout using Data Binding. E.g.: `android:text="@{model.myInt}"`.

Solution is to stringify the value: `android:text="@{String.valueOf(model.someIntegerVariable)}"`

3. Another possibility is that you defined a string in a language specific string file (e.g. `values-de/strings.xml`) and failed to define default value in `values/strings.xml`

Comment: Items 2 and 3 are not suitable, so that leaves item 1. Test class looks like this: @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class GeoWeatherFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun checkWeatherInfoDisplayed() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<GeoWeatherFragment>()

        onView(withId(R.id.feels_like))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}

Comment: @Lobio Please post the code for `GeoWeatherFragment` in your question. It will help to debug this further. Post both class file and layout XML.

Comment: The whole project is here, if it helps. https://github.com/Lobiofrom/Weather